# Any apps in review will remain in the 'Getting ready' state until you add your payment method. I am not getting how to add payment method

Tags: admob, ads, payment

The apps is still  in GETTING READY state for a week and show like this:
If you haven't already, be sure to complete your payment profile in AdMob. Any apps in review will remain in the 'Getting ready' state until you add your payment method.

My AdMOb account is new and trying to implement ad but it is still in getting ready state though I have already added payment profile. Where to add payment method? I am not getting any leads.
Please see the screenshot below and guide me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdAOj.png)

Have added Payment Profile.
Have waited for a weeks.